# Powershell Set-AzDataLakeStoreItemAclEntry Error occured while sending the request

Tags: azure, powershell, acl, data-lake, az

Trying to execute the following command in Powershell ISE

```
Set-AzDataLakeStoreItemAclEntry -Account "********" -Path "/raw2" -AceType Group -Id "******************" -Permissions All
```

I only have the `Az` module installed, no `Rm`

But I get the following error, any suggestions?

```
Set-AzDataLakeStoreItemAclEntry : Error in modifying ACL entries group:************:rwx for path /raw2.
Operation: MODIFYACLENTRIES failed with   Unknown Error: An error occurred while sending the request. Source: mscorlib StackTrace:    at 
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.Store.WebTransport.<MakeSingleCallAsync>d__20.MoveNext().
.
Last encountered exception thrown after 5 tries. [An error occurred while sending the request.,An error occurred while sending the request.,An error occurred while sending the request.,An 
error occurred while sending the request.,An error occurred while sending the request.]
[ServerRequestId:]
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-AzDataLakeStoreItemAclEntry -Account "**********" -Path "/raw2 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzDataLakeStoreItemAclEntry], AdlsException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.DataLakeStore.SetAzureDataLakeStoreItemAclEntry
```